# What is better between "after no contact" and "after lack of contact"?

Tags: phrase-usage

What is better between the following sentences?

> After no contact system withdrew order.

> After lack of contact system withdrew order.

Are they significantly different?

Comment: You might take a look at [this excellent meta post by J.R.](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please?cb=1) and use it as a guide to help get better answers for your questions :)

Comment: @WendiKidd Can you suggest something specific from this guide?

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to expand your sentence slightly:

```
After no contact with [something], the system withdrew the order.

After a lack of contact with [something], the system withdrew the order.
```

In terms of which one is best, 'no contact' is a more direct way of saying it, and 'lack of contact' is more indirect. Furthermore, 'no' is a much more definitive term than 'a lack of', which can mean 'no' or 'not enough of'.

Comment: I want omit some context to make is short. Good hint with '

Comment: I want to omit some context to make it short - Without omit it will be _After no contact with [somebody], the system withdrew the order_. It looks that _no contact_ suits better since less formal, direct and more definitive.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using "After lack of contact...". It is more natural, as well as more formal.

Comment: O.K. I do not want use more formal language want be more direct/communicative - do you think that in both contexts it will be the best "lack of contact".

Comment: @Chameleon More context would help to decide which one fits your needs better, so if you could please expand your question to include more context I will expand my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

The OALD says that "lack of" means, "the state of not having something or not having enough of something."

I would rather use "no contact" and write:

> After no contact, the system withdrew the order.